# ¿Como puedo declara dos variables y dependiendo de cada variable en un switch me devuelva un objeto otro?

Tags: javascript

Bueno no se si me explicado bien en el titulo ya que soy nuevo dejo el código

```
const monedas = 1000;
const nivel = 9;
const Aviso = "";
switch (nivel && monedas) {
  case nivel < 10:
   return Aviso = 'No tienes nivel'
  case monedas < 1000:
    return Aviso = 'No tienes monedas'
  default:
    return Aviso = 'No tienes nivel y monedas'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no puedes usar `return` si no estás en una función. Aparte de eso la lógica no es correcta. Habría que evaluar en primer lugar si no tiene nivel y monedas y a partir de ahí ir descartando por cada valor.

Una forma de hacerlo con `return` sería esta:

```js
const monedas = 1000;
const nivel = 9;

const Aviso = (function(nivel,monedas) {
  switch (true) {
    case nivel < 10 && monedas < 1000:
      return 'No tienes nivel y monedas'
    case monedas < 1000:
      return 'No tienes monedas'
    case nivel < 10:
      return 'No tienes nivel'
    default:
      return 'Tienes nivel y monedas'
  }
})(nivel, monedas);

console.log(Aviso);
```

O, dado que `Aviso` está en el ámbito global, puedes hacer una asignación en el `switch`, pero en ese caso, `Aviso` no puede ser del tipo `const` y tendrás que agregar un `break` en cada `case`.

```js
    const monedas = 1000;
    const nivel = 9;
    var Aviso;
    
      switch (true) {
        case nivel < 10 && monedas < 1000:
          Aviso='No tienes nivel y monedas'
          break;
          
        case monedas < 1000:
          Aviso='No tienes monedas'
          break;

        case nivel < 10:
          Aviso='No tienes nivel'
          break;
          
        default:
          Aviso='Tienes nivel y monedas'
      }

    console.log(Aviso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es comparar el resultado de la expresión con `true`, así:

```
const monedas = 1000;
const nivel = 9;
const Aviso = "";

switch (true) { //TADA!
  case nivel < 10:
   return Aviso = 'No tienes nivel'
  case monedas < 1000:
    return Aviso = 'No tienes monedas'
  default:
    return Aviso = 'No tienes nivel y monedas'
}
```