# ¿Cuantas "Expresiones" o "Parametros" puede tener la declaración Switch case?

Tags: javascript, switch

Por favor si en algo estoy equivocado estaré complacido a su colaborativa corrección.

¿Cuantas "Expresiones" o "Parametros" puede tener la declaración Switch case?

Si nos vamos a que según (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch):

> La declaración switch evalúa una expresión, comparando el valor de esa
> expresión con una instancia case, y ejecuta declaraciones asociadas a
> ese case, así como las declaraciones en los case que siguen.

Decimos entonces que dentro de los paréntesis del `Switch` va una "**EXPRESIÓN**", esto para no estar llamando erróneamente como valor, parámetro u otro y así manejemos un mismo vocabulario.

Ejemplo de una estructura básica:

```
    Switch(expresion){
     case valor: // el valor puede estar entre comas, ser un valor numérico, lógico, puede tener condiciones como &&, ||, no estoy seguro si incluso también puede tener funciones. (si pueden aclarar eso perfecto)
     break;//determina la pausa, se pueden poner varios casos sin break para que estos se unan a la posibilidad o pasen de igual forma (seria como agregarle un "OR"
     default://la opción por defecto si no cae en ninguno de los casos anteriores
    }
```

Ahora, conociendo esto la pregunta actual es,
**¿Con cuantas expresiones pude trabajar el Switch, es esto posible?**

Puedo colocar y evaluar varias expresiones a la vez?
ejemplo:

```
    Switch(expresion1,expresion2){
    case valor1,valor2:
    }
    
    //o puedo evaluar una expresion de función?
    
    Switch(funcion1()){
    case valorFuncion:
    }
```

Comment: En Javascript se suele usar algo como `switch (true) { case Expr1 && Expr2 && Expr9999: ...  case ExprA && ExprB && ExprZ: ...}` o sea, la multiplicidad de evaluaciones se traslada a los `case`. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/337494/29967) hay un ejemplo.

Comment: La documentación establece claramente: _evalúa **una** expresión_. Si permitiera varias diría _evalúa **varias** expresiones_. Por lo tanto allí tienes tu respuesta. En todo caso te interesa también leer sobre [Expresiones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expresiones) en Javascript. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La documentación consultada muestra los casos de uso. No hay casos más extraños que esos.

```
//esto no es posible, solo se permite una expresión    
switch(expresion1,expresion2){
    case valor1,valor2: // error. solo debe haber un valor por case
 }
    
   
// una función sí es posible, siempre que retorne un valor 
switch(funcion1()){
    case valorFuncion: // correcto, un valor por case. El valor debe ser una constante.
}
```